# bitcoin-cli listunspent returns empty list

Tags: segregated-witness, bitcoin-cli, regtest, sendtoaddress

I'm running bitcoind `bitcoind -regtest` and want to send BTC to `bcrt1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvst4ql45` segwit address.

Why listunspent returns empty list after sending somebtc to segwit address?

Check sender has enough bitcoin

```
➜  bin ./bitcoin-cli -regtest getbalance
20.17930334
```

Send BTC

```
➜  bin ./bitcoin-cli -regtest sendtoaddress bcrt1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvst4ql45 15.1
eb5e0047c3c37ad6f020e34febb52da276817196063ba2efc5860aa59f92cff4
```

Get TX

```
➜  bin ./bitcoin-cli -regtest gettransaction eb5e0047c3c37ad6f020e34febb52da276817196063ba2efc5860aa59f92cff4
{
  "amount": -15.10000000,
  "fee": -0.00044248,
  "confirmations": 101,
  "blockhash": "17e269809ab17fb41813f401fc8342a036c18509eb33504e8da87c82c9759e4f",
  "blockheight": 2858,
  "blockindex": 2,
  "blocktime": 1681583966,
  "txid": "eb5e0047c3c37ad6f020e34febb52da276817196063ba2efc5860aa59f92cff4",
  "walletconflicts": [
  ],
  "time": 1681583928,
  "timereceived": 1681583928,
  "bip125-replaceable": "no",
  "details": [
    {
      "address": "bcrt1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvst4ql45",
      "category": "send",
      "amount": -15.10000000,
      "vout": 1,
      "fee": -0.00044248,
      "abandoned": false
    }
  ],
  "hex": "020000000001fd8c020628c3940819bf09b7d2383de51bf6dd8b03fb0ad58fdfc98d85bdf34aec96470000000000feffffff85abf943b973ab67bb3fc88ab922c36b3dd2c2ad61d84d5
```

Generate blocks for confirmation

```
➜  bin ./bitcoin-cli -regtest -generate 101                                                  

{
  "address": "bcrt1qkg54v3hqj4gpl9k0x8evlft3df2cuxetrr6e8l",
....
```

Get UTXOs for the address

```
➜  bin ./bitcoin-cli -regtest listunspent 0 999999 "[\"bcrt1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvst4ql45\"]"

[
]
```

Why listunspent returns empty list, even. after transmission.

Best

Comment: Is `bcrt1qxhx5gq5gwaju2lh0pxnp7qpn4685cwvst4ql45` *your* address (e.g what does `getaddressinfo` say about it?)? `listunspent` is a wallet RPC, it queries your own wallet for UTXOs. If you want non-wallet UTXO lookup, use `gettxout` (though that works by txid:idx, not by address).

Comment: Thank you! Missed that nuance. How can I get UTXO's of an address to build a tx?

Comment: Import them in the wallet first, so it tracks them for you. Then `listunspent` and even higher-level transaction building RPCs will work just fine. Bitcoin Core has no functionality for indexing transactions or UTXOs by address, though you can use `scantxoutset` which will just search through the entire UTXO set for entries matching a given output descriptor (which may include an address).

Comment: I've been struggling to get UTXOs from the RPC. So that's the reason most examples use external APIs to get UTXOs. Thanks